# Finding closest coordinates using $near in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to fetch the closest stored coordinates (which has a date in the future) from my mongo database, but I just get errors. Here is my query:

```
    Event.native(function(err, collection){
        collection
            .find({loc: {$near: req.user.loc }, date: { '>=': today } })
            .limit(10)
            .toArray(function(err, events){
                sails.log.error(err);
                console.log("RESULTS %j",events);
            });
    });
```

I understood that I had to make some indexes to get this working, so I used the line below to make one. I ran that in the mongo console.

```
db.user.ensureIndex({loc:"2d",date:1})
```

When trying to run the query above from within Sails I get the following error:

```
error: MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue not handled: $near
```

I guess that there is something wrong with my query because I do not really understand what I am doing here. I am used to use Waterline methods but I understood that those can't handle $near so I have to use native.